# Should users be able to hide questions (to themselves only)?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to request the ability for users to hide specific questions (for themselves only) so we don't repeatedly see them when we load the site's default page every time they're updated or answered.

My rationale is that I'm stressed out, and I feel like this would relieve some of that stress for some reason. This notion didn't come because of poor questions/answers, but because I don't like to see some things repeatedly. I'm sure some people would hide some of my questions, too, for that matter (I edit a lot).

Is there a likelihood that this will one day be implemented? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good idea and I hope that it will be implemented. There are a lot of questions that I don't know the answer to, or I'm not interested in the answers that might come up. Hiding these questions will decrease the risk of overlooking a question that I find interesting or that I intend to answer.

Hiding tags is not useful enough because on a specific tag there may be questions that I could find interesting and others that I don't. To summarize, I need to cathegorize questions only after I read them.

Answer (score 1):

On some sites such as stackoverflow itself where question numbers are overwhelming my default view is by tags. So you could create a view that shows only the tags you're interested in but that would mean aggressive tag editing.

Comment: You don't need to create a view, just use the *hide tags* feature that already exists.